# Concatenating fields from lines with different numbers of fields

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Given input like this:

```
x y a b c t
p q w w t
a b c d
p q r
```

I'd like to concatenate fields from field 3 up to but not including the last one. If field 3 is the last field, I'd like to insert a placeholder. So given the input above, this is the preferred output:

```
x y a_b_c t
p q w_w t
a b c d
p q _ r
```

The end result is that all lines will have four fields. Is this possible in awk or cut or sed, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk '{
  s = m = ""
  for (i = 3; i < NF; i++) {m = m s $i; s = "_"}
  if (m == "") m = "_"
  print $1, $2, m, $NF}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternate sed version for fun:

```
sed -r 's/  */_/g; s/_/ /; s/_/ /  # convert all to _, unconvert 1st 2
        ts;:s; s/(.*)_/\1 / ;t     # if a trailing third exists unconvert it
        s/ / _ /2                  # else add one
'
```